# Olá, eu fiz uma calculadora simples em C porém a função menu(); se repete duas vezes no laço while, em Pascal uso a mesma lógica e dá certo

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Declaracao de variaveis globais */
int valor;
int valorii;
char opcao;
// Funcao menu
void menu () {
    printf ("===================");
    printf ("C A L C U L A D O R A");
    printf ("===================");
    printf ("\n");
    printf ("Soma: +\n");
    printf ("\nSubtracao: -\n");
    printf ("\nDivisao: /\n");
    printf ("\nMultiplicacao: *\n");
}
// Funcao de soma
void soma (int a, int b) {
    printf ("%d",a+b);
}
// Funcao de subtracao
void sub (int a, int b) {
    printf ("%d",a-b);
}
// Funcao de multiplicacao
void mult (int a, int b) {
    printf ("%d",a*b);
}
// Funcao de divisao
void divisao (int a, int b) {
    printf ("%d",a/b);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
while (opcao != '5') {
    scanf ("%c", & opcao);
    switch (opcao) {
        case '+':
            scanf("%d", &valor);
            scanf("%d", &valorii);
            soma(valor,valorii);
            printf ("\n");
            break;
    }
    switch (opcao) {
        case '-':
            scanf("%d", &valor);
            scanf("%d", &valorii);
            sub(valor,valorii);
            printf ("\n");
            break;
    }
    switch (opcao) {
        case '*':
            scanf("%d", &valor);
            scanf("%d", &valorii);
            mult(valor,valorii);
            printf ("\n");
            break;
    }
    switch (opcao) {
        case '/':
            scanf("%d", &valor);
            scanf("%d", &valorii);
            if (valor && valorii != 0) {
                divisao(valor,valorii);
                printf ("\n");
            } else {
                printf ("Impossivel dividir por zero");
                printf ("\n");
            }
            break;
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aonde vc esta usando a função Menu() ?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, você precisa chamar a sua função `menu()`, porque no seu código atual não está sendo chamado, para um teste simples, você pode chamar após a `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {`, ficando

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    menu();
...
}
```

Seu código basicamente funciona deste jeito durante a execução

```
===================C A L C U L A D O R A===================
Soma: +

Subtracao: -

Divisao: /

Multiplicacao: *
+
1
2
3
-
3
3
0
```

Uma forma de melhorar a interface do seu usuário, seria interessante colocar uma mensagem pedindo pra ele digitar qual tipo de operação ele quer, e após ele digitar, aparecer uma outra mensagem pedindo pra ele digitar o primeiro número, sequencialmente o segundo número, e após isto, uma mensagem mostrando `Resultado: valor`, porque olhando assim, fica difícil de entender que precisa ficar digitando.
Uma outra coisa "ruim" que estou vendo, é esse monte de `switch`, sendo que o `switch` já aceita múltiplos `case`, por quê cada `switch` para cada operação?
Outro ponto a ser destacado, porque variáveis globais? Você só utiliza para as operações passadas como argumento, a melhor prática para isto seria colocar ela também dentro da função `main`.
Outro ponto, na divisão, você só precisa validar se o segundo número é 0, porque um número divido por 0, é "indefinido", mas 0 divido por qualquer número, é 0.
Abaixo segue o seu código melhorado.

```
/* https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/534235/ol%c3%a1-eu-fiz-uma-calculadora-simples-em-c-por%c3%a9m-a-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-menu-se-repete-duas-v */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Funcao menu
void menu() {
    printf ("===================");
    printf ("C A L C U L A D O R A");
    printf ("===================");
    printf ("\n");
    printf ("Soma: +\n");
    printf ("\nSubtracao: -\n");
    printf ("\nDivisao: /\n");
    printf ("\nMultiplicacao: *\n");
}

// Funcao de soma
void soma (int a, int b) {
    printf ("%d",a+b);
}
// Funcao de subtracao
void sub (int a, int b) {
    printf ("%d",a-b);
}
// Funcao de multiplicacao
void mult (int a, int b) {
    printf ("%d",a*b);
}
// Funcao de divisao
void divisao (int a, int b) {
    printf ("%d",a / b);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int valor, valorii;
  char opcao;
  menu();

  while (opcao != '5') {
      printf("Digite a operação: ");
      scanf ("%c", & opcao);
      switch (opcao) {
        case '+':
          printf("Primeiro valor: ");
          scanf("%d", &valor);
          printf("Segundo valor: ");
          scanf("%d", &valorii);
          printf("Resultado: ");
          soma(valor,valorii);
          printf ("\n");
          break;
        case '-':
          printf("Primeiro valor: ");
          scanf("%d", &valor);
          printf("Segundo valor: ");
          scanf("%d", &valorii);
          printf("Resultado: ");
          sub(valor,valorii);
          printf ("\n");
          break;
        case '*':
          printf("Primeiro valor: ");
          scanf("%d", &valor);
          printf("Segundo valor: ");
          scanf("%d", &valorii);
          printf("Resultado: ");
          mult(valor,valorii);
          printf ("\n");
          break;
       case '/':
          printf("Primeiro valor: ");
          scanf("%d", &valor);
          printf("Segundo valor: ");
          scanf("%d", &valorii);
          if (valorii != 0) {
              printf("Resultado: ");
              divisao(valor, valorii);
              printf ("\n");
          } else {
              printf ("Impossivel dividir por zero");
              printf ("\n");
          }
        break;
      }
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) { }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Execução do programa

```
===================C A L C U L A D O R A===================
Soma: +

Subtracao: -

Divisao: /

Multiplicacao: *
Digite a operação: +
Primeiro valor: 5
Segundo valor: 5
Resultado: 10
Digite a operação: -
Primeiro valor: 10
Segundo valor: 10
Resultado: 0
Digite a operação: /
Primeiro valor: 20
Segundo valor: 10
Resultado: 2
Digite a operação: 5
```